# Pandas filtering multiple entries of the same name in one column to give all other related items in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to filter out a single name which has numerous entries in one column to show all other related items with that one name in the other columns using pandas. basically all of pauls data below to be collected into a new dataframe would be perfect

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name' : ['paul','paul','paul','tom','tom','tom'],
'job status' : ['1', '2', '3','2', '2', '1'],
})
```

| Name | job status |
| --- | --- |
| paul | 1 |
| paul | 2 |
| paul | 3 |
| tom | 2 |
| tom | 2 |
| tom | 1 |

into a new dataframe that looks like this

| Pauls job status |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
status = df[df['Name'] == 'paul']['job status']
pd.DataFrame(data={'paul job status' : status})
```

You can do this in 2 steps

1. filter out the needed job status based on the name
2. make a new df containing the new status

Comment: This worked great for what i need, thank you! is there a way to add extra columns relating to paul in your example?

Comment: you can create as many columns as you want by making a separate query for each column.
`col1 = df[df['Name'] == 'paul'][column1_name]
col2 = df[df['Name'] == 'paul'][column2_name]
pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : col1 , 'col2' : col2})
`

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc`

```
name = "paul"
status = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df["Name"]==name,"job status"])

print(status)

  job status
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

To also add other columns, just add them to the second part of `.loc[]`:

```
df_paul = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['Name] == 'paul, ['job status', 'column x', 'column y']])
```